# Adding methods on Controller abstract class

Tags: php, oop, inheritance, abstract-class, laravel-5

I was trying to migrate a Laravel 4.2 app into Laravel 5.0
and previously in Laravel 4.2 you have a BaseController which other Controllers you create can extend, meaning if I add a method inside it. The other controllers will extending the BaseController can use it.

Now on Laravel 5.0, they somehow changed it instead of using class they made use of an abstract class

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\DispatchesCommands;
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller as BaseController;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Validation\ValidatesRequests;

abstract class Controller extends BaseController {

    use DispatchesCommands, ValidatesRequests;
}
```

Now I'm not familiar with what an abstract class is so my main concert is will I still be able to add `functions()` that can be used by other controllers extending it?

So as an example in a controller extending the BaseController

`$this->method_from_base_controller();`

Comment: [Abstract classes](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.abstract.php).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can create for abstract classes methods that will be used in classes that inherits from abstract class.

The main difference between abstract classes and normal classes is that you cannot create objects of abstract classes. You can also create in abstract classes methods you want to be implemented in child classes. [Reference on abstract clasess on php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.abstract.php)